# Evaluate the following limit of an integral

Tags: calculus, limits

Find $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin(nx)}{x^2 +n^2}dx$$
It seems to me that this limit is zero since LDC says I can push the limit inside the integral sign. Then since the limit of the integrand is zero the result follows. Can someone confirm my thinking or give a different argument?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x^2+n^2}$

Comment: See the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma).

Comment: @mtiano: What is LDC?

Comment: I think $\left| \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin nx}{x^2+n^2} dx \right| \le \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{| \sin nx |}{x^2+n^2} dx \le \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{x^2+n^2} dx\le \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{n^2} dx = \frac{2\pi}{n^2} \to 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hence
$$\sup_{x\in \left[0,2\pi\right]}\;\left|\frac{\sin(nx)}{x^2 +n^2}-0\right|\le \sup_{x\in \left[0,2\pi\right]}\;\left|\frac{1}{n^2}\right|\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$

The integrand converges [uniiformly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) to 0, so you are allowed to interchange integration with the limit process.

Comment: Or, just estimate the integral and use the Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Using the fact that $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \qquad -1 \leqslant \sin x \leqslant 1$$ you can come up with the inequality

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \qquad  \left| \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin nx}{x^2 + n^2} dx \right|  \leqslant \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{x^2+n^2}$$

With the change $ u = \frac{x}{n}$ you finally have $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \qquad  \left| \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin nx}{x^2 + n^2} dx \right|  \leqslant \frac{1}{n} \int_0^{\frac{2\pi}{n}} \frac{du}{1+u^2} = \frac{\arctan \frac{2\pi}{n}}{n}$$

and since $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\arctan x}{x} = 1$$ we have $$\frac{\arctan \frac{2\pi}{n}}{n} = \frac{2\pi}{n^2} \frac{\arctan \frac{2\pi}{n}}{\frac{2\pi}{n}} \to 0$$